# How to indicate that all fields are not optional in typed form group

Tags: angular, typescript, angular14

As of Angular 14, reactive forms are strictly typed by default ([Typed Forms](https://angular.io/guide/typed-forms)). This is great. I have implemented a simple login form like below

```js
  form = this.fb.group({
    username: ['', [Validators.required]],
    password: ['', [Validators.required]],
    rememberMe: [true]
  });
  submit() {
    this.authenticationService.login(this.form.value).subscribe();
```

And in the service I have

```js
login(data: { username: string; password: string; rememberMe: boolean }): Observable<any> {
  // Logic to login here
}
```

Typescript infers the type of `form` to be

```js
  form: FormGroup<{username: FormControl<string>, password: FormControl<string>, rememberMe: FormControl<boolean>}>
```

which looks good. The problem arises with `this.form.value` that has a type `Partial<{ username: string; password: string; rememberMe: boolean; }>`. This causes typescript to throw an error

```
Argument of type 'Partial<{ username: string; password: string; rememberMe: boolean; }>' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ username: string; password: string; rememberMe: boolean; }'.   Property 'username' is optional in type 'Partial<{ username: string; password: string; rememberMe: boolean; }>' but required in type '{ username: string; password: string; rememberMe: boolean; }'.
```

Is there a way while declaring the formgroup to indicate that the field will be available in the formgroup value. Currently I am typecasting like below

```js
this.form.value as {username: string; rememberMe: boolean; password: string}
```

The above works but will it have to be typecast for all forms?

Answer (score 22):

It is `Partial` because some controls can be disabled (and potential undefined).

To get all values, use `this.form.getRawValue()`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer though as per my question, I am looking for a way to specify the type not get all values including disabled properties

Comment: Hm, I think you can't resolve it only by types "which controls are enabled", like your _working_ example, which assumes that all fields are enabled, but in reality it may not be so.

Btw, that typecasting can be replaced with `as Required<typeof this.form.value>`

Comment: `Required<typeof this.form.value>` looks neat, will try it out thanks

Comment: getRawValue ist great. In FormBuilder there ist a nonNullable method. Is there a nonDisabled method, too?